# Assemble a video from an array of images with crossfade for transitions

Tags: ios

I am looking to generate an mp4 video from an array of images that are replacing each other in the video with a cross fade animation.

Solution I came up so far for images A and B:

```
A(alpha = 1) overlays B(alpha = 0)
...       (generate enough frames to maintain desired fps)                                 
A(alpha = 0.5) overlays B(alpha = 0.5)         
...       (generate enough frames to maintain desired fps)                                
A(alpha = 0) overlays B(alpha = 1)
```

Then once we have array of overlays image views I can use AVAssetWriter to create a video.

Is there any better solution or third party library which would stitch images into a video with a crossfade animation without a need to set up every frame yourself?

Comment: Does this need to be done at runtime? If not, consider iMovie: http://www.macworld.com/article/1167368/photography/photos-to-movies-how-to-transform-images-into-a-motion-picture.html

Comment: Yes it has to be done at runtime unfortunately. I have animation in my iOS app that I want to share as a video with share sheet.